# Download specific folder from tar.gz file using wget command

Tags: linux, command, wget, tar

I'd like to download and extract specific folder from tar.gz, which is stored on cloud space.
right now what i am following is

```
wget --auth-no-challenge --no-check-certificate --user=myuser --password=mypass <URL>
tar -xvf <Folder>tar.gz
```

now, i only want a specific repo from that extracted Folder.

Folder

|-- Repo1

|-- Repo2

Problem:

1. Space Constraint as the tar.gz is around 8GB.
2. Time taken to download the Tar.

so minimize time and solve space issue i want to partially download specific repo from tar.

i tried

```
wget --auth-no-challenge --no-check-certificate --user=myuser --password=mypass <URL> | tar -xvf Folder/Repo1
```

which obviously does not work.
I am trying to play with it, but couldn't succeed.

any suggestion are appreciated.
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

The command should be something like:

```
wget --auth-no-challenge --no-check-certificate --user=myuser --password=mypass  -O /dev/stdout <URL> | tar -xvf - Folder/Repo1/*
```

1. you need to set where to "download" file (`-O`)
2. you need to tell tar what is the input file (`tar -xvf -`)
3. You may need to add wild card to the path

P.S. Nevetheless you will download entire file.