# Download specific file from tar.gz

Tags: tarfile, tar.gz

I want to extract and download a file from a tar.gz archive, from a web server, but without first downloading the entire archive, because it is large, about 3 GB. I am using a Unix-like environment. How can I achieve this with either a shell command or a with a Python module?

Related tools:

- [5 Ways to Preview ZIP and Download Selected Files in Archive](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/preview-and-download-selected-files-and-contents-in-zip-archive/), On Windows

Related questions:

- [Download specific folder from tar.gz file using wget command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72172943/download-specific-folder-from-tar-gz-file-using-wget-command)
- [How to download only a single file from an online ZIP archive via Powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67031711/how-to-download-only-a-single-file-from-an-online-zip-archive-via-powershell)

Comment: You can't. Such an option would require support at the server end and I am not aware of any that do.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this isn't possible. A tar archive is a linear sequence of entries, and to get to the entry you're looking for, you need to decompress and look at all the bytes that come before it in the file.