Is it possible to access CRAN webpage for previous R package versions?
Does CRAN maintain webpages for previous versions of R packages? E.g. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gt/index.html, but for version 0.10.1? I have tried Wayback Machine, but it is not sufficiently granular in all cases.
I'm trying to browse the dependencies of previous versions without having to download or install anything.

CRAN does not. By going to the Internet Archive and its Wayback Machine you like already exhausted the best existing snapshot mechanism.  Now, the page is generated from the release at hand you could roll something up by hand given the (publically archived as per software licensing conventions) tar.gz.  The code is likely the packages utils and/or tools that are pare of base R.

There's an "Old sources" link on the CRAN page: https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/gt/ and Version 0.10.1 does seem to be listed there. You can get the content of that old package. Everything that's shown on the HTML page should come from that source tar ball. What information were you specifically looking to find?

I don't think you're going to be able to do better than downloading the old source tarball (you can't get just the DESCRIPTION file out without downloading the whole thing, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72402783/download-specific-file-from-tar-gz ; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72172943/download-specific-folder-from-tar-gz-file-using-wget-command ). The source tarballs are usually not very large ...

So now your question is: Does CRAN publish a historical record of dependencies, and the answer is no. There is the (immensely useful) 'current' aggregation in tools::CRAN_package_db() for 'now'.  No historical record of these is provided by CRAN.  But in the grand scheme of things package sources are small: just fetch the source tarball and extract DESCRIPTION as @BenBolker suggested.

Answer to updated question: You can't on CRAN, but you can find the answer on github. From the main landing page, you can switch the branch from master to various versions, including 0.10.1 under Tags.
CRAN does not necessarily make it easy but Posit package manager does. gt 10.1 is available here. Though Evan's comment clarifies they're actually asking a different question, for completeness thanks to
@Ada Lovelace's comment, to get version 0.10.1, scroll down to the bottom. 0.10.1 is there under "Archived versions". Click on it for both the tar.gz and the code to install it: devtools::install_version('gt', '0.10.1').
To kind of answer the clarified question, I believe you can download the tar.gz, extract the contents, and check the DESCRIPTION file to read the dependencies.

I'm trying to browse the dependencies of previous versions without having to download or install anything.

@Evan, you should add that comment to your question.  The CRAN page for a package is constructed from the package contents.  So you could reconstruct it, but not if you don't want to download it.

@gabagool I get gt 0.11.1 at that URL you posted, the same version as at CRAN.

@AdaLovelace scroll down to the bottom. 0.10.1 is there under "Archived versions". Click on it for both the tar.gz and the code to install it devtools::install_version('gt', '0.10.1'). I should have made that clear in my answer.

@gabagool Yes you should have :)  Thanks for the added detail though.  And what you describe is actually not an answer to OP's problem but merely a restatement of "old sources are kept due to licensing requirements" and remotes (formerly devtools) knows how to download from there and install it. So no news at 11pm, sadly.

@gabagool the GitHub solution seems to solve this. Thanks!
